# .js/.css code from external source not loading while only in https

Tags: jquery, css, linux, https, apache2

There's a problem here.. I used to include google fonts in my website running on a http server. At the moment, I try to run the same website on a https server instead, but it seems that all the external sources like Google fonts or jQuery are not included. 
It seems to work in firefox on my linux, but not on windows!!
Is there a way to generally use external code on my https server?

I hope you can help me.

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link relatively to the protocol, basically, wherever you see http:// change it to just //